# How to developing ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Web app using JWT auth

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have to develop a website (web app) using ASP.net core.

**Background:**

1. It preliminary uses Asp.Net core 3.1, but it may change to Asp.net core 6. (For backend & front end)
   I tried to use JwtBearer
2. There is an REST API for JWT authentication (owned by the others). I would like to adopt it for authenticating the user name & password
3. The webapp will receive the token from the REST API. The token will be stored in the session and refresh the token within a certain period.
4. I could retrieve some basic user's info in the token. But i want to add some extra info (e.g. role) for authorization

**Issue:**
I found the most tutorials about the web api only.

So, i have no idea how could develop the part of authorization. How to build the customize claims after receiving the token.

For the above scenario, i have read some examples about using OpenIdConnect. Should i use OpenIdConnect instead of JwtBearer?

Thanks